# What is the best way to store free-form data?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, database-design

I'm using Zend Framework and MySQL. The users of my application will have the ability to store arbitrary amounts of data, structured like tables. The problem is, I won't know the "columns" before hand. So, I can't create a ready-made table or ready made Zend Framework Model.

In a previous version of the application, a table schema was generated automatically from the data. This worked well. The problem this time is that I don't know how to create a Zend Framework Model to represent an arbitrary data source. Does anyone have any idea of what the best strategy is for my case? And no, rethinking my application requirements isn't an option :).

By the way: In an even older version of the application, the data was stored as JSON. This approach was very slow.

Comment: This is what NoSQL solutions like MongoDB are for.

Comment: @ceejayoz: That looks great, but unfortunately I need to stick with Zend Framework and MySQL. Thank you though.

Comment: Sometimes, the best solution is to go up the chain until you get to someone who can change the requirements. Trying to cram a square peg into a round hole isn't much fun for all involved, especially when there's a perfectly good square hole you could be using.

Comment: Create a table that has a large text field (longtext) and store a serialized version of your data object in that field. Use the Model's after and before find events to serialize/deserialize into a member variable with a getter/setter. I've done it in a few projects, works great.

Comment: Thanks all! But would the downvoter please explain their reasoning?

Comment: @lucifurious: Thank you! What method of serializing would you suggest?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Well, it's your call really. If you're working exclusively in PHP there is no reason not to use the built-in **serialize** and **unserialize**. HOWEVER, they do not always work well with the SimpleXML extension. If you're expecting to de/serialize SimpleXML objects be aware. I will post some code I have...

Comment: `protected static function _unserialize( $value )
{
 try
 {
  if ( self::_isSerialized( $value ) )
  {
   if ( $value instanceof SimpleXMLElement )
    return simplexml_load_string( $value );

   return @unserialize( $value );
  }
 }
 catch ( Exception $_ex )
 {
 }

 return $value;
}

protected static function _serialize( $value )
{
 try
 {
  if ( $value instanceof SimpleXMLElement )
   return $value->asXML();

  if ( is_object( $value ) )
   return serialize( $value );
 }
 catch ( Exception $_ex )
 {
 }

 return $value;
}`

Wow, this sucks. I'm going to post an answer. Please don't down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't use NoSQL, take a look at the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model.  It allows for flexible attributes via a sort of metadata model.

It may not perform well if you have a large amount of data, and can be a bit painful to maintain vs.a  fully relational schema.  I would not recommend it as a first option, but if you REALLY can't know the schema up front it is one way you could go.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

Comment: Thank you! I found an EAV plugin for Zend Framework, so I'll probably use that.

Answer (score 0):

I felt inspired since I was providing an answer.... I whipped up a little class that'll do this for you...

### Table

```
kick_ass_data_t
```

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `kick_ass_data_t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key_text` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `value_text` mediumtext,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lmod_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

### Class

```
<?php
/**
 * Property Bag
 */

class KickAssProps
{
    /**
     * gets a property from a database bag.
     * If $remove is true, item is deleted after retrieved.
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $defaultValue
     * @param bool $remove
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProperty( $key, $defaultValue = null, $remove = false )
    {
        $_result = $defaultValue;

        //  Lookup key
        if ( null === ( $_model = $this->_loadProperty( $key ) ) )
        {
            $_model = new KickAssData();
            $_model->key_text = $key;
            $_model->value_text = self::_serialize( $_result );
            $_model->create_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

            if ( ! $_model->save() )
            {
                //  bitch alot...
            }
        }
        else
            $_result = self::_unserialize( $_model->value_text );

        if ( $remove )
        {
            if ( ! $_model->delete() )
            {
                //  bitch alot...
                }
        }

        return $_result;
    }

    /**
     * sets a property in a database bag.
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return \KickAssProps $this
     */
    public function setProperty( $key, $value = null )
    {
        //  Lookup key
        if ( null === ( $_model = $this->_loadProperty( $key ) ) )
        {
            $_model = new KickAssData();
            $_model->key_text = $key;
            $_model->create_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
        }

        $_model->value_text = self::_serialize( $value );

        if ( ! $_model->save() )
        {
            //  bitch alot...
        }

        //  Allow chaining...
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a property from the database bag
     * @param string $key
     * @return KickAssData
     */
    protected function _loadProperty( $key )
    {
        //  Example sql
        //  $_sql = 'select * from kick_ass_data_t where key_text = :key_text';

        //  read row from database however you want... this is how I'd do it in Yii (http://www.yiiframework.com)
        $_model = KickAssData::model()->find(
            'key_text = :key_text',
            array(
                 ':key_text' => $key
            )
        );

        return $_model;
    }

    /**
     * Serializer that can handle SimpleXmlElement objects
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected static function _serialize( $value )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( $value instanceof SimpleXMLElement )
                return $value->asXML();

            if ( is_object( $value ) )
                return serialize( $value );
        }
        catch ( Exception $_ex )
        {
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Unserializer that can handle SimpleXmlElement objects
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected static function _unserialize( $value )
    {
        try
        {
                if ( self::_isSerialized( $value ) )
            {
                if ( $value instanceof SimpleXMLElement )
                    return simplexml_load_string( $value );

                return @unserialize( $value );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception $_ex )
        {
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Tests if a value needs unserialization by unserializing the value then 
     * re-serializing. If both are successful then it's cool. I know this is 
     * slower but it guarantees data integrity in my database.
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected static function _isSerialized( $value )
    {
        return !( false === @unserialize( $value ) && $value != @serialize( false ) );
    }
}
```